# How to Find Record Set Value is Number or String?

Tags: vb6

**Original**:

Using VB6

```
If rsCardEvent(4).Value = Str Then
 TimOut = rsCardEvent(4)
Else
 TimeOut = Left(TimOut, 2) & ":" & Mid(TimOut, 3, 2) & ":" & Right(TimOut, 2)
End If
```

Getting Type MisMatch Error.
How To Find Record Set Value is String or Number

Exactly i need

If Number means print number like Time Format (HH:MM:SS)
else 
print string value

Coding Help for the above condition

---

**Edited Version**:

I'm working with an `ADO.Recordset` object and am trying to determine the data type of a column at run-time. I need to handle the column value differently in my code depending on its underlying data type. If the column value is a string, I want to work with the value as-is. If it is a number, I want to treat the number as an packed time and convert it to `HH:MM:SS` format (i.e. the number `120537` would be converted to the string `"12:05:37"`).

Below is some example code that demonstrates what I want to achieve. However, when I run this code I get a "Type Mismatch" error:

```
If rsCardEvent(4).Value = Str Then
   TimOut = rsCardEvent(4)
Else
   TimeOut = Left(TimOut, 2) & ":" & Mid(TimOut, 3, 2) & ":" & Right(TimOut, 2)
End If
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know the type of TimOut (string?) and the type of the column in your query. Can you post the SQL and also the underlying type in the database of the field you are reading? (If it is only one field)

Comment: I added a rephrased version of the question, but kept the original in case my edited version isn't true to the author's original intent. @Jash, if you agree the edited version matches want you wanted to say and don't mind me making this change, I can remove the original and keep the edited version.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how you can really be getting different data types in rsCardEvent(4). Are you sometimes running a different query? Or is the underlying field a variant field? Also the Else branch of your If completely ignores rsCardEvent which looks weird.

Comment: @MarkJ: I was wondering the same thing after looking at the code again. I have a feeling the database table really needs an extra column, rather than trying to store two kinds of information in the same field and then trying to guess what type of data is currently stored there. IsNumeric, for example, could be tricky. What happens if the fields contains "100.52"? IsNumeric will return True, and then the code will assume it contains an HHMMSS time, and now there's a bug. So now you add a Len() check to make sure you have 6 characters, but then someone enters "123.45" into the field ;)

Comment: @Jash, can you give us some more background information about the program that uses this code? For example, what kind of information is stored in rsCardEvent(4) other than HHMMSS times?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Visual Basic 6 function library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32s6akha.aspx). There are functions that can help you determine the underlying type of a value.

There are quite a few but you might find these useful:

- [IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1.aspx)
- [IsDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=279), if `rsCardEvent` is an ADO recordset, you could check the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318(VS.85).aspx) property. Something like this:

```
    Select Case rsCardEvent(4).Type
        Case adBSTR, adChar, adVarChar, adWChar, _
           adVarWChar, adLongVarChar, adLongVarWChar
            ' It is a string '
        Case Else
            ' It is not a string '
    End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1.aspx) function available in VB6.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
If TypeName(rsCardEvent(4).Value) = "String" then
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5422sfdf.aspx

Comment: If TypeOf rsCardEvent(4).Value is String then - is Not accepting Showing Error in "TypeOf" and "is String"

Comment: Yep, TypeOf only works with objects, but have you tried TypeName like Jack suggested?